# windows-server-2003, windows server, download utility from command line , http or ftp or any other protocol , from one command only

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-command-prompt, utility

I need to know if there is a utility built-in to Windows Server 2003 that I can use from the command line to download a file using only one command.
Basically I know that I can download from ftp using the `ftp` utility but in order to do that I need to do first `ftp open` and then pass the other commands so it doesn't help me because I need to do perform the download only from one command. The download may be performed through http, ftp or any other protocol.

```
OS Name: Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003 Enterprise x64 Edition
OS Version: 5.2.3790 Service Pack 2 Build 379
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing built-in I'm aware of. If you have PowerShell installed you can use `System.Net.WebClient` for that, even though you may still want a wrapper for ease of use:

```
$wc = New-Object Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile('http://...', file)
```

But if you first need to install something, then there are many other options out there, too.

Comment: PowerShell is not native on 2k3 right?

Comment: @noraj: No. But nowadays that shouldn't really matter. Either you can install it (in an ancient version), or no longer have a long-unsupported OS running (hopefully).

Comment: it doesn't matter for a production purpose. But I was more seeing this in a security ethical hacker purpose, like finding an utility or short script way that help the security research to download a backdoor. So actually it matters a lot to me. But yeah most people don't core of this.

Comment: @noraj: I think for those purposes BITS, or XMLHTTP with VBScript are somewhat common

Answer (score 1):

[tftp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol) is perfect for this stuff! it requires a tftp server, but means you can do one line file download commands.

It's been removed from the most recent MS server and client OS's because it makes downloading & installing virus payloads so easy!

```
tftp -i x.x.x.x get file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use ncftp for this kind of thing: http://www.ncftp.com/

Answer (score 0):

wget and curl (open source utilities) should each be able to meet your needs.

wget:
http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

curl:
http://curl.haxx.se/

(Despite the "haxx" domain name, it is a very safe and common open-source tool.)

-Waldo